# How Does one use Group By in a select?

Tags: mysql

I have a result set that I'd like to return in a particular way

Location, date

Is is possible to have location return once but have multiple dates return only for that location:

E.g.

```
select location, date from access group by date;

Texas
    3/11/13
    2/21/13
Montana
    1/20/13
Ohio
    12/20/12
    1/18/13
    2/2/13
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to group by date, but by location:

```
SELECT location, GROUP_CONCAT(date) FROM access GROUP BY location
```

This will select each location and a comma-separated list of the dates.  Note that [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has a relatively low limit before it starts truncating characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `GROUP BY` in your case because you are not aggregating a column. You just need to run the simple select statement and format the result in the application level.

```
SELECT location, date FROM access
```

When you want to use `GROUP BY`, it is understood that you want to aggregate some of the fields. 
See [GROUP BY FUNCTIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

select location, date from access group by location,date;
try this